# In sharepoint 2013 multilingual not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, multilingual

We have installed the English language pack and configured variation for Spanish language and I have also changed my browser language setting. Unfortunately my site is still showing an English language interface. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Check is the site is configured to use other languages.
Also set your language preferences in your profile.